# Winetricks ubuntu 23.04 won't launch

Tags: wine, 64-bit

After fresh install getting the following:

```
$ winetricks
Executing mkdir -p /home/usr
------------------------------------------------------
warning: You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------
WINEPREFIX INFO:
Drive C: total 28
drwxrwxr-x  7 usr usr 4096 May 22 14:47 .
drwxrwxr-x  4 usr usr 4096 May 22 15:15 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 usr usr 4096 May 22 14:47 ProgramData
drwxrwxr-x  6 usr usr 4096 May 22 14:47 Program Files
drwxrwxr-x  6 usr usr 4096 May 22 14:47 Program Files (x86)
drwxrwxr-x  4 usr usr 4096 May 22 14:47 users
drwxrwxr-x 18 usr usr 4096 May 22 14:47 windows

Registry info:
/home/usr/.wine/system.reg:#arch=win64
/home/usr/.wine/user.reg:#arch=win64
/home/usr/.wine/userdef.reg:#arch=win64
------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------
warning: wine cmd.exe /c echo '%AppData%' returned empty string, error message "" 
------------------------------------------------------
```

However,

```
$ wine cmd.exe /c echo '%AppData%'
C:\users\usr\AppData\Roaming
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To troubleshoot the issue, you can try the following steps:

1. Make sure you have Wine installed correctly on your Ubuntu system. You can do this by running `wine --version` and ensuring that it returns the installed version information.
2. Verify that Winetricks is installed properly. You can reinstall it by running `sudo apt install winetricks`.
3. Try launching Winetricks with additional debugging output by running `WINEDEBUG=+all winetricks` or `WINEDEBUG=-all,+relay,+seh winetricks`. This will provide more detailed information about what might be going wrong.
4. If the above steps don't resolve the issue, consider creating a new, clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX and testing Winetricks there. You can do this by running `WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 winecfg` to create a new 32-bit prefix. Then, run `WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 winetricks` to launch Winetricks in the 32-bit prefix.

If the problem persists, it may be helpful to provide additional information, such as any error messages or logs generated when attempting to launch Winetricks.

Comment: '$ wine --version
wine-8.0 (Ubuntu 8.0~repack-4)
'

Comment: 2 did multiple times.

Comment: 3 gives exactly the same output as just 'winetricks'. 4 worked. Would love 64 though

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with Xubuntu 23.04 but at least it's working when installing `wine-development`.

So this should work:

```
sudo apt purge wine
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install wine-development
winetricks
```

If it does not work try to delete ~/.wine or reinstall winetricks.