# Winetricks "od: wine: no such file or directory"

Tags: wine, winetricks

I had wine tricks running, then I reinstalled both wine and winetricks and now I get the following message:

```
$ winetricks
od: wine: No such file or directory
------------------------------------------------------
warning: You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
------------------------------------------------------
grep: /home/zach/.wine/*.reg: No such file or directory
------------------------------------------------------
WINEPREFIX INFO:
Drive C: total 28
drwxrwxr-x  7 zach zach 4096 Dec 11 15:32 .
drwxrwxr-x  4 zach zach 4096 Dec 11 15:32 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 zach zach 4096 Dec 11 15:32 ProgramData
drwxrwxr-x  6 zach zach 4096 Dec 11 15:32 Program Files
drwxrwxr-x  6 zach zach 4096 Dec 11 15:32 Program Files (x86)
drwxrwxr-x  4 zach zach 4096 Dec 11 15:32 users
drwxrwxr-x 18 zach zach 4096 Dec 11 15:32 windows

Registry info:
/home/zach/.wine/*.reg:
------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------
warning: wine cmd.exe /c echo '%AppData%' returned empty string, error message "" 
------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried fully reinstalling it like suggested in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1468904/winetricks-ubuntu-23-04-wont-launch), but that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: The error message suggests you installed `winetricks` but NOT the corresponding WINE binaries.  Are you SURE you have Wine installed?

Comment: Yep, when I run `wine --version` it spits out `wine-8.0.1 (Ubuntu 8.0.1~repack~3ubuntu2)`